python compile with multiple functions
(edit: simpler example with functions)
I'm having trouble compiling a python AST with functions that call each other. A minimal example:
def main():
    str = """
def fn_2():
    print("got so far")
        
def fn(input):
    fn_2()

fn("abc")

"""    
    mod = compile(str, "testing", 'exec')
    exec(mod)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wvw/git/n3/fun3/python/test_compile.py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/wvw/git/n3/fun3/python/test_compile.py", line 23, in main
    exec(mod)
  File "testing", line 8, in <module>
  File "testing", line 6, in fn
NameError: name 'fn_2' is not defined

When I add the function to the original file, it works:
def fn_2():
    print("got here")

def main():
    str = """
def fn_2():
    print("got so far")
        
# def fn(input):
#     fn_2()

fn("abc")

"""    
    mod = compile(str, "testing", 'exec')
    exec(mod)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

But, that is not my goal :-) I'm working on a source-to-source compilation project that spews out a number of functions that call each other.
Clearly, there are some inner workings of compile that I am unaware of. I'm hoping someone with metaprogramming experience in python will be able to shed some light!

what about using ast to compile it into a module then call fn from the module?
https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html

@ThisGuyCantEven the end result would be the same though, wouldn't it - a compiled module. compile accepts both AST and strings - see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile

I actually did find time to test this more, even though the posted answer works. When I tested this in python3.8, the original (non-working) code example you provided actually ran excatly as expected without any errors for me ¯\(ツ)/¯

I can provide my own solution (mostly thanks to this post!)
def main():
    str = """
def fn_2():
    print("got so far")
        
def fn(input):
    fn_2()
"""    

    mod_code = compile(str, "<fun3>", "exec")

    new_refs = {}
    exec(mod_code, globals(), new_refs)
    # print(new_refs) # find all compiled codes here
    
    for name, code in new_refs.items():
        # register each compiled code as global
        globals()[name] = code
        
    new_refs['fn']("abc")
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

It seems that each compiled code needs to be separately registered in the global namespace.
